# Button Clicking works when self-clicked, not automaitcally

Tags: javascript, setinterval, greasemonkey

i'm new here. I try to work with greasemonkey to copy all whispers from a Path of Exile trade-search.

It all works great when I click the meta-button I created myself. But whe I run the function via SetInterval it jest deletes the buttons, and doesn't click them before..

What do I miss? I already tried a lot..

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    https://nope
// @version      0.0.0.1
// @description  clicks whispers of poe-trade
// @author       PJ
// @license      no
// @match        https://www.pathofexile.com/trade*
// ==/UserScript==




var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Copy next";
input.onclick = CopyWhisper;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input);


function CopyWhisper()
{
    var allbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName("whisper-btn");
    var firstbutton = allbuttons[0];
    firstbutton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    firstbutton.remove();

}

setInterval(CopyWhisper, 5000);
```

Comment: Seems like it's working as written for me, using Chrome and TamperMonkey (runs greasemonkey scripts in Chrome).  It triggers a click every 5 secs, presses the button, and copies the data as appropriate to the clipboard. It seems after that, you're not doing anything with the data though. It won't keep appending that data to the clipboard in one long string, but overwrites the last clipboard data. You need to get/store that data that's added to the clipboard. Also, if you move away from the browser window, it will keep clicking buttons but not copy the data.

Comment: Hmm, will have to try again.. I use autohotkey to write to a file everytime clipboard changed

Comment: For me it doenst copy every 5 sec. it deletes the buttons every 5 sec, yes. But it only copies to clipboard if i actually mouseclick in the window (not on the buttons)

Comment: Correct, that was the gist of my comment on moving away from the browser window, my apologies for the poor wording. My suggestion, look at the developer docs on interacting with the clipboard here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard  There are security and browser specific considerations around this which could cause your code to function like you describe, where the button press works but not the longer lived process using setInterval. Might not matter, it looks like they are using the execCommand function to copy the text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to remove the button by finding it with the classname "whisper-btn" whereas the button element doesn't have that class assigned, resulting in nothing being assigned to 'allbuttons' variable.
You can either add that classname to the button OR try document.getElementsByTagName("input") instead.

Take a look at this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9fe8zc6u/

```
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Copy next";
input.onclick = CopyWhisper;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:120px;right:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input);


function CopyWhisper()
{
    var allbuttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var firstbutton = allbuttons[0];
    firstbutton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    firstbutton.remove();

}

setInterval(CopyWhisper, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks - but the 'input'-button is a button I added to test the function - and it works. when i click my button greasemonkey finds the first whisper button, clicks it, and deletes it afterwards. the buttons i click are found correctly with the  whisper-btn-class. Just not when i call the function from setInterval instead of my Button

Comment: @srishti-ganjoo if you go to https://www.pathofexile.com/trade/search/Metamorph/Ab3LSL in your browser you'll see the buttons. They do indeed have the class as mentioned <button class="btn btn-default whisper-btn">Whisper</button>